# Equivalent of std::pair in C

Tags: c++, c, std-pair

What is the C equivalent of `std::pair` from C++? I'm trying to find the equivalent on the web and can't find anything but explanations of what it does.

Comment: You cant have an equivalent because C doesn't have templates. You could manually make a struct with 2 members, but that's the closest you'd get.

Comment: C++ is largely a convenient C, `#define make_pair(name, t1, t2) struct name##_pair { t1 a; t2 b; };`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There isn't one. `std::pair` is a template, and C doesn't have anything similar to templates.

For a given specialisation of the template, you can define a structure that's more or less equivalent; so that `std::pair<int, double>` is similar to

```
struct pair_int_double {
    int first;
    double second;
};
```

but you've chosen the wrong language if you want a generic template.

Answer (score 5):

While the other answers are correct in saying that C does not have templates, the assumption that you can not have a generic pair type is wrong. If you really need a generic type, that is, you don't want to manually define a `struct` for each pair of types you want to use a pair for, you are left with 3 options.

Firstly, you could use a struct containing two `void*` types, and use these pointers as generic storage pointers for you data. (This is needlessly complicated and I would not generally recommend it)

Secondly, if the amount of types for your pair structure is known beforehand, you could use a `union` in your struct, for example

```
struct pair 
{
  union
  {
    int first_int;
    float first_float;
  };
  union
  {
    int second_int;
    float second_float;
  }
}
```

Or thirdly, you could use parametric macros to generate struct definitions of types you need, without constantly repeating yourself.

Or, alternatively think of a way to write your code that does not rely on templated types.

Comment: I don't see anything generic here

Answer (score 3):

`std::pair` in C++:

```
template <class t1, class t2>
struct pair {
  t1 first;
  t2 second;
}
```

`std::pair` takes advantage of templates, so each concrete instantiation defines a new class `std::pair<myT1, myT2>`.

There's no such thing in C, you may have to declare a different struct each time, or use void *...

```
struct pair {
  struct myT1 first;
  struct myT2 second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers made clear, C doesn't have anything similar to C++ templates.

However, you may use `void*` as a way to store addresses of variables of any type, by casting to a pointer of the data type you want.

Following this, a possible implementation of a pair structure in C would be as follows:

```
struct pair {
    void* first;
    void* second;
};
```